# How to change input tags language dynamically?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to give the user an option to change the input language in the same text field. For example while writing English the user should have option to switch to arabic in the same html text field. I need to change the language after the html text field is completely loaded.

Comment: cwanjt tell me how it is duplicate to what you suggested there?

Comment: @AbdullahKhan There's a very, very useful comment in the comment thread of the accepted answer "_... you can tailor it for your usage_"!

Comment: @Teemu , well i have seen all the answers but i could not find what i want. All the answers are related to one time language change, which i am already able to. The accepted answer also does the same, it does not change language after the element or text field is loaded while i need to change it after text field is loaded.

Comment: ?? Then why don't you ask what you need? Also, SO is not a copy-paste service, you try, you fail, you ask, and you show some effort in the question ...

Comment: @Teemu perhaps i mentioned what i needed moreover, i edited my question perhaps you can help now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Usually an application shouldn't care about how text is written into input fields, that is a task of the operating system, handled by different input methods (IM).
All the application has to do is to handle Unicode for text and use a font that can display these characters.